# Debugging Helpers in Qtcreator don't work on Linux

Tags: linux, qt, gdb, qt-creator

and sorry for mess English.

In theory while debugging in qt-creator show fields of classes defined in Qt.
But it doesn't do it and display only  or mem address.

I think that the problem in GDB or Python scripts.

GDB loaded from http://origin.releases.qt-project.org/gdb/ gives what is described above.

I tried to Build GDB myself with config flags

```
configure --prefix=<DIR> --target x86_64-linux-gnu --with-python
```

and

```
configure --target x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-nls --with-libiconv --with-expat --with-python
```

but they crash while starting from Qtcreator

i'm running on Ubuntu 12.10 x64
Qt version is 4.8.4 (from Git)
and creators are 2.5.2(from qt-project site) and 2.6.81 (git)
GDB versions: 
 build myself - 7.5
 download from qt-project - 7.4.1

on Win8 subject works fine in combination QtCreator(2.6.81)-Qt-4.8.4-MinGW-GDB-7.5(build myself from source with Py. support)

UPD: Try to build with http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/trees/master/dist/gdb 
it didn’t help

SOLUTION: Qt libs didn't contain debug simbols. I was caught by flag **-debug-and-release**. It work in macOS and windows (MinGW) but not in Linux. Be careful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the version of Qt you use has been built with debug symbols? What does `readelf -S /path/to/your/libQtCore.so` say?